# JPA não atualiza registro filhos

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou com um probleminha com o JPA que é o seguinte, eu tenho a classe `ModeloEstoquePecas`, aonde teoricamente preciso deletar tudo primeiro, que são os registros filhos da classe `EstoquePecas`, com o código abaixo que eu vou estar colocando o que acontece e não consigo resolver ele teoricamente deleta, mais na hora que vai excluir o registro pai que é o `EstoquePecas` ele encontra os registros filhos e dá erro para excluir por causa que ele achou os filhos, como resolver essa situação.

```
public List<ModeloEstoquePecas> destroyByCodigoEstoquePecas (List<ModeloEstoquePecas> listaModeloEstoquePecas) {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    if (listaModeloEstoquePecas != null) {

        try {

            em.getTransaction().begin();

            for (ModeloEstoquePecas modeloEstoquePeca : listaModeloEstoquePecas) {

                modeloEstoquePeca = em.merge(modeloEstoquePeca);
                em.remove(modeloEstoquePeca);
            }

            em.flush();
            em.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }  finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    return listaModeloEstoquePecas;
}
```

Log:

> br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina.controller.exceptions.IllegalOrphanException:
>   This EstoquePecas
>   (br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina.model.entity.EstoquePecas[
>   codigoEstoquePecas=8 ]) cannot be destroyed since the
>   ModeloEstoquePecas
>   br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina.model.entity.ModeloEstoquePecas[
>   modeloEstoquePecasPK=br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina.model.entity.ModeloEstoquePecasPK[
>   codigoEstoquePecas=8, codigoModelo=1 ] ] in its modeloEstoquePecasList
>   field has a non-nullable estoquePecas field.

```
public class ModeloEstoquePecas implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected ModeloEstoquePecasPK modeloEstoquePecasPK;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "dataAlteracaoModeloEstoquePecas")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataAlteracaoModeloEstoquePecas;
@JoinColumn(name = "codigoEstoquePecas", referencedColumnName = "codigoEstoquePecas", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
private EstoquePecas estoquePecas;
@JoinColumn(name = "codigoModelo", referencedColumnName = "codigoModelo", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Modelo modelo;

public class ModeloEstoquePecasPK implements Serializable {

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "codigoEstoquePecas")
private int codigoEstoquePecas;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "codigoModelo")
private int codigoModelo;

public class EstoquePecas implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "codigoEstoquePecas")
private Integer codigoEstoquePecas;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nomeEstoquePecas")
private String nomeEstoquePecas;
@Lob
@Column(name = "descricaoEstoquePecas")
private String descricaoEstoquePecas;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "dataCadastroEstoquePecas")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataCadastroEstoquePecas;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "quantidadeEstoquePecas")
private Integer quantidadeEstoquePecas;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "valorCompraEstoquePecas")
private BigDecimal valorCompraEstoquePecas;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "valorVendaEstoquePecas")
private BigDecimal valorVendaEstoquePecas;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "usuarioEstoquePecas")
private String usuarioEstoquePecas;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "estoquePecas")
private List<ModeloEstoquePecas> modeloEstoquePecasList;
```

Resolvido:

```
private void jButtonEstoquePecasExcluirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                           

EstoquePecas estoquePecas = new EstoquePecas();

if (jTextFieldIncluirCodigoEstoquePecas.getText().isEmpty() == false) {
    estoquePecas.setCodigoEstoquePecas(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldIncluirCodigoEstoquePecas.getText()));
}

EstoquePecasCRUD estoquePecasCRUD = new EstoquePecasCRUD();
estoquePecasCRUD.setAcaoCRUD("EXCLUIR");
estoquePecas = estoquePecasCRUD.modeloPadrao(estoquePecas);

if (estoquePecas != null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Estoque De Peças Excluído Com Sucesso.", "Excluir - Estoque De Pecas", 1);

    formWindowOpened(null);

} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Estoque De Pecas Não Excluído.", "Excluir - Estoque De Pecas", 0);
}

}

public Integer destroy(Integer id) {

try {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    EstoquePecasJpaController estoquePecasJpaController = new EstoquePecasJpaController(em.getEntityManagerFactory());
    estoquePecasJpaController.destroy(id);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
return id;
}
```

Comment: Como estão as classes `ModeloEstoquePecas` e `EstoquePecas`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa atualizado ele crio um ModeloEstoquePecasPK automaticamente também o que não entendi, mas ele só usa pra deletar e pesquisar o registro.

Comment: obrigado, mas consegui resolver o problema, bom era muito simples, eu estava tentando fazer um for excluindo o ModeloEstoquePecas e estava dando erro na transação, foi corrigido simplesmente chamando o destroy do EstoquePecas passando o ID aonde ele já exclui os filhos e eu me matando sozinho.